# Why Hilbert Transform is terrible choice for amplitude demodulation of broadband signals?

Tags: hilbert-transform, math, amplitude-modulation, envelope

A reference [answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/81945/34391) empirically demonstrates that Hilbert envelope does not work well for the (**amplitude**) demodulation of a broadband signal. I am looking for the math which explains why...

Comment: To be precise: the reference question is about "envelope detection", not AM demodulation. For single carrier AM signals, they are, but for most other signals, they are not.

Comment: @Hilmar Are you saying "they [Hilbert transform] are" _terrible_, for single component signals?

Comment: That depends on what exactly you mean by "single component signal". What I am saying is the following: The Hilbert Transform will not give you anything that looks remotely like the "envelope" of an audio signal as most people would define that envelope. In other words "Magnitude of Analytic Signal" $\neq$ "Envelope" for many signal types and definitions of "envelope".

Answer (score 9):

It's not only a matter of "broadband or not":

[image]

The Hilbert estimate degrades for *multi-component* signals - that is, whatever we can't draw *without lifting our pen, left-to-right,* in time-frequency (STFT), because then, we have multiple amplitudes to track:

$$
A_1(t) \cos(\phi_1 (t)) + A_2(t) \cos(\phi_2 (t))
$$

and there's no way of "combining" $A_1$ and $A_2$ for the desired effect. This isn't to suggest that a satisfactory $A$ doesn't exist, only that Hilbert won't yield it: the Hilbert transform yields the [analytic representation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Analytic_signal#/Properties), $A(t)\cdot e^{j\phi (t)}$, whose real part is the original signal, and the "envelope" is $A(t)$, which *happens to match* the signal's $A$ only if the signal itself can be written as $A \cdot \cos$. And more precisely, it's $|A(t)|$, but in practice $A(t) \geq 0$ anyway.

It just happens so that, for real-world broadband signals, it's likelier to have multiple components. The degradation can very well occur within narrowband signals also, but it's less likely. Explained further in [synchrosqueezing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/72238/50076) (includes math on what $A$ and $\phi$ can be, to not be fully arbitrary).

#### Extended note

General amplitude extraction isn't something a simple 1D transform like Hilbert can handle. It is intrinsically tied to time-frequency resolution and subject to Heisenberg's uncertainty. In my expressions above, $A$ and $\phi$ must satisfy certain criteria for any method to work, plus the criteria I stated for Hilbert transform to work. Most importantly, **the highest significant** (high energy) **frequency of $A(t)$ must be much smaller than the lowest significant frequency of $\cos(\phi(t))$**:

[image]

If the carrier is a single pure sine, "much smaller than" relaxes to "strictly less than" (there's dependence on $\phi''$, see reference). In Gideon's derivation, $A(y(t))=x(t)e^{−j\omega_c t}$ is only true if the highest frequency of $x(t)$ is less than $\omega_c$ - and in the single pure sine carrier case, it'll work even if $x(t)$ is multi-component.

See my other answer for a proof of these claims.

Comment: [messy code](https://pastebin.com/LYUEjLNE) for who's interested

Comment: Right! The analytic signal model doesn’t match what our view of the signal is… so it screws up. I’ll have to dig in synchrosqueezing. Looks interesting.

Comment: For the graphs it would be useful to see what the expression is for the waveforms to make it clearer the point you're trying to make. In your equation, the Amplitudes and phases are arbitrary functions of time (not just sinusoids) and additionally the complex exponential has an arbitrary phase function. Therefore, it's not clear that you can't find an $A(t)$ and $\phi (t)$ to match.

Comment: @David Fair, though I intend the answer to be simple, and I think in general the interpretation of $A, \phi$ is clear. I did refer a post that addresses this (see under "What are SSWT's assumptions?")

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Are these criteria and the ones below described somewhere I can cite? I'm probably looking in the wrong place, but these are valuable.

Comment: @EliS "valuable" without voting is a curious form of gratitude.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Upvoted. Gratitude has many forms. I'm still getting used to what is considered most valuable here.

Comment: @EliS Aye, just plethora users getting answers then vanishing forever without clicking a button. -- The derivation is my own, I don't know if it's been done elsewhere - you could cite it [like so](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/86205/122022) (with John Muradeli). The closest I've learned of later is [Bedrosian's Theorem](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/66866/50076), but I don't know if it's exactly same, and it doesn't automatically generalize to discrete per not accounting for aliasing.

Answer (score 4):

### Amplitude extraction / AM demodulation criteria

I shall prove,

1. $y(t) = x(t) \cos(\omega_c t)$ demodulates perfectly to $|x(t)|$ if

   - A) $x$'s highest frequency, $\omega^\text{max}_x$, is $<\omega_c$
   - B) $\omega^\text{max}_x + \omega_c < \omega_s/2$ (sub-Nyquist)
2. $y(t) = \cos(\omega_m t) \cos(\omega_c t)$ always demodulates to $|\cos(\text{min}(\omega_m, \omega_c)t)|$.

1 says "pure sine can carry any message whose highest frequency is below its own". It will also be shown, a pure sine is the *only* carrier which can perfectly demodulate.

2 says "the envelope is always the lesser frequency in a product of sines".

Both are for the discrete setting. Implications for STFT and CWT are described.

### Criteria notes

- "can demodulate" in this post refers only to "directly from analytic signal" (without further steps)
- "pure sine" includes complex sinusoid
- All $\omega$ in discrete/Nyquist context includes *aliased* frequencies; `Ctrl + F` "Alias note"
- This answer is mainly about real-valued $y(t)$, but many conclusions carry directly and others with appropriate adjustment

### Notation / identities

- Analytic signal: $\mathcal{A}\{y(t)\} = y(t) + j \mathcal{H}\{y(t)\}$
- Hilbert transform: $\mathcal{H}$
- product $\Leftrightarrow$ sum: $\cos(A) \cos(B) = .5 (\cos(A + B) + \cos(A - B))$
- "Demodulation", "amplitude extraction", and "envelope extraction" are all used interchangeably and refer to the same thing: recovering $|x|$ from $\mathcal{A}$ via $|\mathcal{A}|$.

### Proof of 2

We know $\mathcal{H}\{\cos(\omega t)\} = \sin(|\omega| t)$, hence (assume $\omega \geq 0$ for now)

$$
\mathcal{A}\{\cos(\omega t)\} = \cos(\omega t) + j\sin(\omega t) = e^{j\omega t}
$$

A minimal AM-carrier is

$$
\cos(\omega_m t) \cos(\omega_c t),
$$

and we know (ignore $.5$) that's just

$$
\cos((\omega_m + \omega_c)t) + \cos((\omega_m - \omega_c)t).
$$

Simplify notation, take $A=\omega_m t$ and $B=\omega_c t$. By linearity of Hilbert,

$$
\mathcal{H}\{\cos(A + B) + \cos(A - B)\} = 
\sin(A + B) + \sin(|A - B|)
$$

Then for modulus, $|\mathcal{A}\{\cos(A + B) + \cos(A - B)\}|$, we have

$$
\sqrt{(\cos(A + B) + \cos(A - B))^2 + (\sin(A + B) + \sin(|A - B|))^2}
$$

and [one can show](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7Ccos%28A+%2B+B%29+%2B+cos%28A+-+B%29+%2B+i*%28sin%28A+%2B+B%29+%2B+sin%28%7CA+-+B%7C%29%29%7C) that's

$$
\begin{cases}
2|\cos(B)|, & A > B\\
2|\cos(A)|, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

which is same as

$$
2|\cos(\text{min}(A, B))|.
$$

In original notation, this reads (now don't ignore .5)

$$
\boxed{ |\mathcal{A}\{ \cos(\omega_m t)\cos(\omega_c t)  \}| = |\cos(\text{min}(\omega_m, \omega_c))| }
$$

so whether we like it or not, Hilbert considers the lesser frequency the "modulator". To preserve the "message", we should ensure the envelope is additionally $>0$ so the modulus on the right side has no effect - easily accomplished by adding a constant, which we can then subtract.

Small caveat, the $A, B$ notation conceals the fact that the derived identity requires $\omega_c + \omega_m \geq 0$ (see [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7Ccos%28%28A+%2B+B%29*t%29+%2B+cos%28%28A+-+B%29*t%29+%2B+i*%28sin%28%7CA+%2B+B%7C*t%29+%2B+sin%28%7CA+-+B%7C*t%29%29%7C)), but that's a non-issue. Lastly, one can redo the derivation with $\omega<0$, and sines instead of cosines, to obtain the same result (which covers every possible sign combination, hence proving it's a non-issue).

### Proof of 1

Suppose the message is $\cos(\omega_{m_0}t) + \cos(\omega_{m_1}t)$, so we have

$$
\left(\cos(\omega_{m_0}t) + \cos(\omega_{m_1}t)\right) \cos(\omega_c t).
$$

We know that's (ignore $.5$)

$$
[\cos((\omega_{m_0} + \omega_c)t) + \cos((\omega_{m_0} - \omega_c)t)] + \\
[\cos((\omega_{m_1} + \omega_c)t) + \cos((\omega_{m_1} - \omega_c)t)] \phantom{+.}
$$

By linearity of Hilbert, we have above but with sines (and modulus around the $-$). Simplifying notation again,

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{A}\{\cdot\} 
= & [\cos(A + C) + \cos(A - C) + \cos(B + C) + \cos(B - C)] + \\
j & [\sin(A + C) + \sin(|A - C|) + \sin(B + C) + \sin(|B - C|)]
\end{align}
$$

Now, we conjure a trick; we know $C > A$ from our assumption that $\omega_c$ is the greatest. Then,

$$
\sin(C - A) = \sin(|A - C|), \ \ \text{if}\ C > A
$$

and we rewrite the imaginary part as

$$
\sin(C + A) + \sin(C - A) + \sin(C + B) + \sin(C - B)
$$

We know

$$
\sin(a + b) + \sin(a - b) = 2\sin(a)\cos(b),
$$

and hence,

$$
2\cdot (\sin(C)\cos(A) + \sin(C)\cos(B)).
$$

Together with reals, we factor and obtain

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{A}\{\cdot\} 
= & 2\cos(C)[\cos(A) + \cos(B)] + \\
j & 2\sin(C)[\cos(A) + \cos(B)]
\end{align}
$$

which under modulus is

$$
\sqrt{4\cos^2(C)(\cos(A) + \cos(B))^2 + 
  4\sin^2(C)(\cos(A) + \cos(B))^2} = \\
\sqrt{4(\sin^2(C) + \cos^2(C))(\cos(A) + \cos(B))^2} = \\
2 |\cos(A) + \cos(B)|.
$$

Retrieving our ignored $.5$ and reverting notation, we thus have

$$
|\mathcal{A}\{\left(\cos(\omega_{m_0}t) + \cos(\omega_{m_1}t)\right) 
\cos(\omega_c t))\}| = |\cos(\omega_{m_0}t) + \cos(\omega_{m_1}t)|.
$$

Lastly, we notice that the real and imaginary parts under modulus, are linear in addition - so adding $\omega_{m_2}$, $\omega_{m_3}$, etc will not introduce dependence on $\omega_c$. Furthermore, the $\sin(C)$ will still factor with the modulators having unequal amplitudes:

$$
2\cos(\omega_{m_0}t) + 3\cos(\omega_{m_1}t)
$$

would yield, for the earlier imaginary part,

$$
2\cdot (2\sin(C)\cos(A) + 3\sin(C)\cos(B)).
$$

Thus, the general result (for any $K$ number of modulators) is

$$
\boxed{\left|\mathcal{A}\{\cos(\omega_c t)
\sum_{i=0}^{K-1}A_i\cos(\omega_{m_i}t)
)\}\right| = \left| 
\sum_{i=0}^{K-1}A_i\cos(\omega_{m_i}t) 
\right|}.
$$

Notice, this summation is identically the Discrete Fourier Transform, except with cosines instead of cisoids. However, we note that the DFT, for a real input, is identically a summation of real cosines and sines, as the imaginary part must sum to zero.

If we can show that the modulus remains independent of $C$ even with sines, then we've proven what we sought, since as the sum on right hand side becomes a DFT equivalent, which can build *any* messenger $x(t)$. Put differently, any $x(t)$ we pick is possible to rewrite as that sum.

### Proof of 1, part 2

Take

$$
\left(\cos(\omega_{m_0}t) + \sin(\omega_{m_1}t)\right) \cos(\omega_c t).
$$

Simplify notation ahead of time. We know that's (ignore $.5$)

$$
[\cos((\omega_{m_0} + \omega_c)t) + \cos((\omega_{m_0} - \omega_c)t)] + \\
[\sin((\omega_{m_1} + \omega_c)t) + \sin((\omega_{m_1} - \omega_c)t)] \phantom{+.}
$$

and $\mathcal{H}\{\sin(\omega t)\} = -\text{sgn}(\omega)\cos(\omega t)$. Suppose again the individual $\omega$'s are non-negative; then the $+$ stay negated, but $(\omega_{m_1} - \omega_c)$ double-negates into $+$. Hence,

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}\{\cdot\} = 
& [\sin((\omega_{m_0} + \omega_c)t) + \sin(|\omega_{m_0} - \omega_c|t)] + \\
& [-\cos((\omega_{m_1} + \omega_c)t) + \cos((\omega_{m_1} - \omega_c)t)] 
\phantom{+.}
\end{align}
$$

and, simplifying notation, we obtain

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{A}\{\cdot\} 
= & [\cos(A + C) + \cos(A - C) + \sin(B + C) + \sin(B - C)] + \\
j & [\sin(A + C) + \sin(|A - C|) - \cos(B + C) + \cos(B - C)]
\end{align}
$$

Now we apply

$$
\cos(a - b) - \cos(a + b) = 2\sin(a)\sin(b)
$$

hence

$$
2\sin(B)\sin(C)
$$

Repeating our arguments from part 1, we again factor $\sin(C)$ from the sines in the imaginary part, and $\cos(C)$ from the real part, and in total obtain

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{A}\{\cdot\} 
= & 2\cos(C)[\cos(A) + \sin(B)] + \\
j & 2\sin(C)[\cos(A) + \sin(B)]
\end{align}
$$

which under modulus is

$$
\sqrt{4\cos^2(C)(\cos(A) + \sin(B))^2 + 
  4\sin^2(C)(\cos(A) + \sin(B))^2} = \\
\sqrt{4(\sin^2(C) + \cos^2(C))(\cos(A) + \sin(B))^2} = \\
2 |\cos(A) + \sin(B)|.
$$

Repeating the rest of the arguments from part 1, and additionally observing that we did not make $\omega_{m_1}$ depend on $\omega_{m_0}$ in any way and hence they can be equal, and that we can have $A_i=0$ while $B_i \neq 0$ and vice versa, we have thus shown,

$$
\boxed{ \left|\mathcal{A}
\{
\cos(\omega_c t)
\sum_{i=0}^{K-1}\left(A_i\cos(\omega_{m_i}t) + B_i\sin(\omega_{m_i}t)
 \vphantom{\frac{.}{.}}\right)
\}
\right| = \left| 
\sum_{i=0}^{K-1}\left(A_i\cos(\omega_{m_i}t) + B_i\sin(\omega_{m_i}t)
 \vphantom{\frac{.}{.}}\right)
\right|}
$$

Finally, to prove my claim that real DFT is just sum of sines and cosines - observe, `irfft` does, for any bin $k$,

$$
(A_k + jB_k)\cdot (\cos(2\pi k n) + j\sin(2\pi k n)) \\
[A_k\cos(2\pi k n) - B_k\sin(2\pi k n)] + j[A_k\sin(2\pi k n) + B_k\cos(2\pi k n)]
$$

and the imaginary part must sum to zero, leaving

$$
A_k\cos(2\pi k n) - B_k\sin(2\pi k n)
$$

which is

$$
A_i\cos(\omega_{m_i} t) + B_i\sin(\omega_{m_i} t)
$$

in disguise.

#### Remark: discrete vs continuous

All identities used are pointwise relations, hence regime-agnostic. The two critical differences are,

1. Existence of Nyquist for discrete; note that $\cos(A)\cos(B)$ contains $\cos(A + B)$, so the sum of carrier and messenger's peak frequencies cannot exceed (or reach) half of sampling rate.
2. What qualifies as "pure sine"; in discrete time, this means integer number of cycles. This yields a single DFT bin, otherwise, we get "spectral leakage" - frequencies above and below $\omega_c$, which violates our core assumption, and also makes the carrier multi-component as far as the proof (and DFT) is concerned (or, to be precise, the discrete Hilbert transform is no longer the sampling of the continuous Hilbert transform of an infinite pure sine, just like the DFT of such a sine is no longer coincides with sampling of a pure sine's CFT via DTFT).

The messenger will be as well-preserved as our satisfying of above. It's also another reason we favor high frequency carriers: the difference between exact number of integer cycles and not, is much fewer in samples, so our error is smaller.

As to whether this proof holds in continuous-time... dunno. This proof uses the convenience of trig identities thanks to sums - in CT we have integrals. The relations continue to hold for arbitrarily large $N$, so perhaps we argue, in Riemannian spirit, that the continuous case is also proven via $N\rightarrow \infty$.

### Proof of 1, code

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import hilbert

for N in (128, 129):  # even & odd cases
    t = np.linspace(0, 1, N, 0)
    for f_c in range(N//4):  # //4 to avoid alias per *amplitude
        # make general `x` with freqs all the way up to (but excluding) `f_c`
        x_f = np.random.randn(N) + 1j*np.random.randn(N)
        # same as zeroing between +f_c and -f_c, w/ + reflected to - for Herm. symmetry
        x_f[f_c:] = 0
        x = np.fft.ifft(x_f).real
    
        c = np.cos(2*np.pi * f_c * t)
        y = x * c
    
        assert np.allclose(np.abs(x), np.abs(hilbert(y)))
```

### Proof: multi-component

To prove the envelope won't extract in presence of multiple carriers, we simply make $\omega_c$ the smallest frequency in above derivations, which is exactly what we'd write for two carriers modulated by the same envelope (and invoke proof 2). Then, we can no longer use $\sin(|A-C|) = \sin(C-A)$, which breaks our ability to factor out and eliminate $\omega_c$, thus retaining variable dependence on $\omega_c$.

### Conclusion

This completely disproves the notion that bandwidth alone determines ability to demodulate, as our signal can span everything from DC to Nyquist with maximum energy and still demodulate.

The multi-component case *requires* time-frequency analysis, since the decomposition into "carriers" and "modulators" is non-unique, and component separability is intrinsically bound by time-frequency resolution and Heisenberg's principle. See my other answer.

### STFT, CWT implications

STFT and analytic CWT are simply bandpassed analytic signals. Hence any conclusions drawn for the general analytic signal carry over. Most notably, neither can perfectly extract the amplitude of anything but an AM pure sine: multi-components and AM-FMs do not perfectly demodulate via $|\mathcal{A}|$, and linear filtering cannot change that. [Synchrosqueezing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/72238/50076), however, can: the reassignment step is nonlinear and can reduce every temporal slice to a single point, which via invertibility guarantees perfect recovery.

### Observations

"demodulation", "envelope extraction", "amplitude extraction" below all refer to obtaining $|x(t)|$ via $|\mathcal{A}|$ (without further steps). I use "demodulation" for brevity. "message" is $x(t)$.

1. Exact demodulation is *only* possible with a pure sine carrier. Follows directly from the multi-component proof, where any frequency that's not the pure sine will qualify as "component".
2. Exact demodulation is *only* possible with messages whose maximum (nonzero) frequency is below *half of Nyquist*, i.e. $< f_s/4$. The worst case is max frequency of $f_s/4 - 1$, for which the best possible carrier is $f_s/4$, that results in populating $x(t)c(t)$ all the way up to Nyquist (see next point). Else, alias.

   - Another motivation to DC offset our message, since otherwise $|x|$'s max freq is typically unbounded (even for a pure sine), while ensuring $x \geq 0$ yields $x=|x|$.
   - Note, per previous distinction, an unbounded $|\mathcal{A}\{y(t)\}|$ doesn't mean an unbounded $x$ and violation of any criteria. But it does mean, if we expect $x \geq 0$ (e.g. if $x$ is supposed to be the amplitude function of some AM-FM signal), then we aren't in clear and $x$ isn't recovered.
3. Spectrum of $x(t)c(t)$ is simply spectrum of $x$ shifted to $c$'s bin; suppose its freq is $f_s/4$:

$$
x(t)c(t) \Leftrightarrow 
X(f) \star C(f) = 
X(f) \star \delta(|f| - f_s/4) = 
X(|f| - f_s/4)
$$

[image]

from this we get another perspective on why $\omega_m < \omega_c$ must hold: if it doesn't, then `fft(x)`, when shifted, overlaps itself and aliases.

4. Exact demodulation only occurs if $y$'s spectrum is even-symmetric about some bin, separately (but identically) for positive and negative frequencies. Follows 1, 2, and 3. However, this is a necessary but *not sufficient* criterion: possible to have such symmetry but not recover original $x$ (e.g. carrier is two pure sines of equal amplitude in adjacent bins).
5. The "necessary and sufficient" version of 4 additionally requires that $y$'s spectrum have an odd number of non-zero samples, and that the central sample is greater than or equal to the sum of absolute values of all other samples. Central sample = DC (can have only one), and worst case to guarantee $|x| = x$ is $X[k=0] = \sum |X[k\neq 0]|$, which is much greater than what's required in practice ($X[0]=|\text{min}(x)|$). Note (4) doesn't aim for $x=|x|$, but this "necessary and sufficient" guarantees $x=|x|$.
6. $\text{bw}(x) \leq \text{bw}(y)/2$, assuming no alias ($/2$ i.e. $y$'s one-sided spectrum). Follows from 3 and linearity: the best case is a pure sine carrier, where $\text{bw}(x) = \text{bw}(y)/2$ - anything else and we're adding more shiftings of `fft(x)`, thus expanding `fft(y)`. Also hence, multi-component carriers will alias `fft(x)` (per overlaps, and not to be confused with aliasing $y$).
7. $\text{bw}(|\mathcal{A}\{y(t)\}|)$ for multi-component carrier is almost always unbounded: note when we don't cancel $C$ in the derivations, we get an irreducible sum of sines and cosines under the square root. In fact it may be possible to prove that the multi-component case is *always* unbounded. At the same time, it can certainly be "close enough to" bounded, as is the case with the modulus of STFT and analytic CWT.
8. (Alias note) Infinite valid carriers and message frequency shifts: $\omega_c$ and the rest, in a discrete setting, include the *continuous* $\tilde \omega_c$ that become $\omega_c$ after sampling. For example, if $f_s = 200\text{Hz}$, then $\tilde f_c = 300, 500, 700, ... \text{Hz}$ become $f_c = 100 \text{Hz}$ after sampling. The neat thing is, there's infinite qualifying continuous carriers and shifts of $\hat x(t)$, but bandwidth of the message must still remain sub-Nyquist.

Comment: @DanBoschen Thanks for the remarks, I've cleared up [comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBgMj.png), let me know if there's still disputes or I missed something.

Comment: Deleting my comments that no longer apply…

Answer (score 2):

Assume that we have a signal $$x(t)=\cos(\omega_1 t) + \cos(\omega_2) + 3$$ with a carrier $$c(t) = \cos(\omega_c t)$$ that is not known apriori.

Than, for the amplitude modulated signal$$y(t)=x(t)c(t),$$

under the assumption of $\omega_1,\omega_2 < \omega_c$, the analytic signal is $$A(y(t))=x(t)e^{-j\omega_c t}.$$ Here, $x(t)$ can be extracted by $$\left|A(y(t))\right|=x(t)$$.

Now, assuming that we have two carriers, with similar assumptions ($\omega_1,\omega_2 < \omega_{c_1}, \omega_{c_2}$)
$$c_2(t) = \cos(\omega_{c_1} t) + \cos(\omega_{c_2} t);\space y_2(t)=x(t)c_2(t),$$ the analytic signal is $$A(y_2(t))=x(t)\left(e^{-j\omega_{c_1} t}+e^{-j\omega_{c_2} t}\right).$$ Here, $\left|e^{-j\omega_{c_1} t} + e^{-j\omega_{c_2} t}\right|$ is not constant and therefore the demodulation is not possible.

Comment: Can also simplify $x(t)$ to just one cosine, and note then $y_2$ is equivalently four fixed-amplitude carriers, so multi-component, and still not necessarily broadband. Good example.

Comment: I wanted to show that two signals with one carrier do demodulate...

Comment: That's a point certainly worth clarifying. Updated my answer.

Comment: To clarify the last sentence should read demodulation by simply extracting the magnitude of the analytic signal is not possible, however note that we can multiply $A(y_2(t))$ by either $e^{j\omega_c_1 t}$ or $e^{j\omega_c_2 t}$ and assuming the bandwidth of $x(t)$ is less than $\omega_c_1$ or $\omega_c_2$ we can low pass filter to demodulate (recover) $x(t)$.  Further since $x(t)$ is real we could also demodulate by multiplying by $(\omega_c_1 +\omega_c_2)/2$ and then multiply that result by $(\omega_c_2-\omega_c_1)/2$ if we could maintain perfect carrier synchronization (no offsets).

Comment: @DanBoschen, I assumed no knowledge about the carrier. Also, we demonstrate the problem with the broadband carrier, which means no bandwidth filtering.

Comment: After reviewing some math, I found that for the single pure sine carrier, indeed any $x(t)$ can demodulate to $|x(t)|$ as long as its highest frequency is only _strictly_ below the carrier's lowest (rather than much lower than), and their combined max freqs are below Nyquist, to avoid aliasing, which I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I believe if we use complex waveforms there is no requirement - the signal and the “wideband” carrier can be completely arbitrary and still separable: for every rotation or change in phase and change in amplitude we make in modulating, the carrier is equally changing the phase and amplitude of our modulation signal. To demodulate we just rotate in opposite phase and scale amplitude back in opposite direction. It need not be a tone or narrowband. What condition would make that unrecoverable if we know the carrier exactly and have perfect synchronization?

Comment: @GideonGenadiKogan See my comment above to Overlord. If you allow for full complex representations (as we commonly do in radio implementations using "I" and "Q" datapaths the carrier can be arbitrarily wideband and of any trajectory. In order to demodulate however we must always have full knowledge of what the carrier is (carrier recovery in the receiver). Spread Spectrum can be an example of using a wideband waveform as a "carrier".

Comment: @DanBoschen My application is vibration analysis in which the signal is real rather than complex and the carrier is always unknown.

Comment: @DanBoschen If we know the carrier and the full signal is simply some other function times the carrier, then there is no problem to solve? `answer = x / carrier`

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon the purpose of the "carrier" is to translate the waveform  for whatever purposes (such as a regulatory spectrum allocation, or antenna size or propagation characteristics,  etc). We multiply it by the same carrier (once recovered) to move it back. My whole point was I don't think the last sentence is true: demodulation is possible regardless if it is constant or not; the answer as it stands suggests otherwise (I was just trying to be helpful).

Comment: @DanBoschen Yes but I think OP is working in his own context of 1) an unknown carrier and 2) Hilbert transform. "Not possible" is false even with an unknown carrier, but not with 2).

Comment: I retracted my upvote since the question's intent appears to be precise math, and while the spirit of this answer's derivation is accurate, the math is completely wrong.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon, why is the math wrong? Would u please suggest a correction (edit)?

Comment: My entire answer is the correction; $A(y(t))=x(t)e^{-j\omega_c t}$ is disproven in proof 2, and $A(y_2(t))$ in proof 1: for both, in the general case $x(t)$ vanishes entirely (and for the second case it always vanishes). There's no shortcuts to deriving their exact expressions.

Comment: It's a bit concerning having this upvoted, I think a disclaimer should be added that it's wrong and only right in a special case. Sorry if my earlier comment was blunt but you requested detailed math and I delivered, which you took no interest in.